# como puedo hacer validaciones que solo se ingresen numeros o letras por consola?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

hola buenas tengo una duda, sera que puedan ayudarme a crear la logica para que al ingresar datos por consola les mande error si digitan letras o numero

//validar solo numeros

```
            console.WriteLine("Ingrese Id:");
            int Identificador = Console.ReadLine();
```

//aqui pensaba usar la funcion isNumber pero el while no me la admite asi

```
             while (!IsLetters(Identificador)) {

         console.WriteLine("Ingrese Id:");
        int Identificador = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

pero el programa por consola no no me acepta el isLetterns y no puedo crear un metodo especifico para eso, entonces el metodo donde esta es de tipo de una clase.

tambien con de letras a numeros no puedo hacer la conversion de que mande error o lo devuelva si entre un nombre ejemplo haiga una letra

```
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre :");
            string Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
```

aqui si estoy en cero, no se como podria hacerse, les agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: El metodo "IsLetter" seria lo correcto. Pero no colocas el codigo. ¿Podrias colocar? Porque es asi... mientras no sea "IsLetter" deberias solicitar que ingrese nuevamente. Ademas dices que no puedes crear un metodo especifico?

Comment: Ademas podrias colocar ejemplo de una entrada valida y otra invalida? Porque en el titulo dices solo numero o solo digito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo ver si es numero y volver iniciar el bucle:

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre :");
string Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
int numericValue;
bool isNumber = int.TryParse(Nombre, out numericValue);
if(isNumber){
   Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre :");
   continue;
}
```

Comment: es que  que haces para que te funcione el isNumber , ami me dice que eso no existe

Comment: Me falto agregar el using

Comment: a ok voy a probar gracais

Comment: seria mucha molestia si te pido ayuda de ingrese identificacion para que no se pueda ingresar letras @andres.veiro

Comment: Recuerden tener cuidado que como se esta utilizando "TryParse de int", validara como "ingreso correcto" un numero por fuera del rango de "int". Dejo el ejemplo online [https://dotnetfiddle.net/1SM89d](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1SM89d) que no valida al ingresar "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"

Answer (score 0):

En el codigo que envias como ejemplo tienes el metodo "IsLetter" dentro de un while. Es por ese camino. PEro no colocas el codigo de "verificar". Por eso hay varias formas de "verificar si es digito numero o alfanumerico". Por ejemplo con Expresion Regular.
si se utiiza un TryParse o Parse, puede ocasionar un error dependiendo de la "longitud" de la entrada (o sea numeros muy grandes)

Te dejo un ejemplo para ejecutarlo online con "regex"

- [validacion-consola-ingreso-solo-numeros-o-letras-con-regex](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pqyGGq) > https://dotnetfiddle.net/pqyGGq

Utilice un metodo con esta validacion (pero ahora que lo pienso se deberia llamar IsNumber y utilizarlo en positivo). Te dejo como recomendacion

```
public static bool IsLetter(string input){
    return !Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$"); 
}
```

Cuando ejecutas el demo online, este es el resultado de la consola

```
Hello World
Ingrese el nombre :
1234
Ingrese el nombre :
Yoda
Su nombre es:
Yoda
Ingrese el ID :demo
Ingrese el ID :12345
Su ID es:12345
```

Aqui el codigo completo simple

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                
 public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    
    string nombre = string.Empty;
    do {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre :");
        nombre = Console.ReadLine();

    } while (!IsLetter(nombre));

    Console.WriteLine("Su nombre es:");     
    Console.WriteLine(nombre);      
    
    string id = string.Empty;
    do {
        Console.Write("Ingrese el ID :");
        id = Console.ReadLine();

    } while (IsLetter(id));

    
    Console.Write("Su ID es:");     
    Console.WriteLine(id);  
}

public static bool IsLetter(string input){
    return !Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$"); 
}
}
```

Hay otras opciones para detectar si es solo numero o letra en cadenas mas largas. Pero en este caso simple no creo que amerite algo asi.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia